# How to call a particular javascript function from .js file in karate feature file

Tags: karate

Suppose I have saved followings functions in a Utility js file.

```
function getCurrentDate(){
return 'date';
}

function getMonth(){

return 'Oct';
}
```

Please help me how any of these methods can be accessed in feature file.

I tried following code but it is not working.

```
* def fun = call read('Utility.js')

* def result = getData()
or
* def result = fun.getData()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Karate, a JS file can contain only one function and it does not need a name, take a closer look at the examples.

I don't really recommend combining multiple functions into one file, it just makes things much harder to maintain. But if you really insist, here's how:

```
function() {
  return {
    getCurrentDate: function(){ return 'date' },
    getMonth: function(){ return 'month' }
  }
}
```

EDIT: a much better answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49384760/143475

Comment: But maintaining too many files of js will be overhead . Provided solution is also not a good approach in terms of readability.

Comment: just create one feature file that has as many in-line JS functions as you want declared and re-use it. done !

Comment: Feature file will also be fine. However , do we have any way to reuse particular function from a feature file having many java script function? I have checked documentation but not able to figure it out.

Comment: really not sure what you are concerned about, split your features depending on what you want to re-use. if some JS is declared and not used, it is ok, why are you worried ?

Comment: You can call `def functions = call read('classpath:reusable.js')` and in same feature file try `def x = functions.getCurrentDate( )`.  Hope this helps others trying to figure out on calling custom functions that are in javascript file.

Comment: @MKod how do you maintain the structure. Shall we keep all js files in classpath ? if i keep in a folder and give that folder name it gives error

Answer (score 0):

```
* def data = karate.read('classpath:<path>/getRandomString.js')(<inputToTheFunctionIfAny>);
```

The above code works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).